# Simulate iBeacon region enter and exit by turning bluetooth on and off

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ibeacon

When I am testing with beacon emulator I can turn bluetooth on and off to simulate a user enter and exit the beacon area. However this is not possible when testing with real beacons since there are no switches to enable or disable them. Therefore, is it possible to simulate this by turning bluetooth on and off in the actual iphone? Is the result the same? Does turning on bluetooth result in an immediate bluetooth scan by iOS?

Comment: Did you find a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your mac to generate ibeacons if it have bluetooth 4.0 (https://github.com/mttrb/BeaconOSX) and with that project you can enable or disable the virtual beacon. You can also use another idevice to generate a ibeacon signal.

Comment: Yeah but what I want to know is the ideal way of testing beacons without walking around using a real beacon . Because when you emulate the beacon it will always give you consistant results , however when testing with real beacon this could differ.